# Set max value of an input by a variable : Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to set the max value of "quantity" input type number to the quantity in database: for exemple if there is 10 product A in database, user cannot enter more than 10 in quantity field, here is what i tried :

in html page :

```
<tr class="tableau-contenu" th:each="p : ${panierItem}"> <!--"panier item" is the item in the cart-->
            <td class="smal" th:text="${p.id}"></td>
            <td th:text="${p.name}"></td>
            <td th:text="${p.categorie.name}"></td>
            <td th:text="${p.prix}"></td>
            <td>
                <p th:text="${max}"></p> <!-- this is a test-->
                <input type="number" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48" min="1"
                       th:value="p.quantity"
                        th:max="${max}">
            </td>

            <td class="smal">
                <a class="icon" th:href="@{delProduitFromPanier(id=${p.id})}"><i class="fa-solid fa-minus"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

in the controller, i made a @postmapping method when user trie to add a product in cart :

```
    public String addToPanier(Model model, @RequestParam(name = "id") Long id) {
       
        Produits produit = produitRepo.findProduitById(id);
        int max = produit.getQuantite();
        model.addAttribute("max", max);
        System.out.println("max value of quantity : "+ max);
        panierService.addToPanier(produit); //add to cart
        return "redirect:/panier"; 
    }
```

max variable print correctly the max quantity of product but for some reason it isn't displayed in my html page